# On button click fire Ctrl+Shift+A using jQuery

Tags: jquery

In my application I have one button, when user click on that button it will fire Ctrl+Shift+a operation. Is there any possibility to do that using jQuery.

```
$('#btnClick').click(function(){
// Cntrl+Shift+a operation will perform
});
```

Comment: Please more details. How is `Cntrl+Shift+A` operation is bound to the first button?

Comment: I am creating browser extension in that i am providing one button. Let's assume if user open firefox browser and click on my extension then the extension contains one button named as "uninstall" If user click on that Uninstall button then immediately mozilla firefox Add-On window should be open.

Comment: have a look here http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/15-keyboard-event-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

This way you can trigger keypress event

```
$('#btnClick').click(function(){
    var evt = $.Event("keypress");
    evt.keyCode = 65;
    evt.ctrlKey = true;
    evt.shiftKey=true;
    $(document).trigger(evt);   //instead document, you might want to specify specific element on which you want to handle keypress-event
});
```

for more information, [look at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894617/execute-ctrld-on-button-click)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(function($){
  $('#btnClick').click(function(e){
    var c = $.Event("keypress");
    c.keyCode = 65;
    c.ctrlKey = true;
    c.shiftKey=true;
    $(document).trigger(c);
  });

  /* to view keypress on console use below: */
  $(document).keypress(function(x){
    console.log(x);
  });
});
```

View demo: http://jsfiddle.net/renishar/572WS/3/

in Firefox you can open the extension page simply by:

opening '**about:addons**' in address bar of Firefox.

Comment: When you click on Ctrl+Shift+a manually in firefox browser then extensions page will open. Open jsfiddle link in firefox and test it.The jsfiddle example says when you click on button then Ctrl+Shift+a will fires but the extensions page is not opening. @ReNiSh

Comment: as per your question the answer is right, cntrl-shift-a is shortcut only for firefox, you have not specified it in your question

Comment: Okay that is right, but it is not firing in firefox.Is there any other way to do that when button is clicked(Ctrl+Shift+a) then extension page should open in firefox.

Comment: Thank you the above comment(opening 'about:addons' in addressbar) solved my Issue. I just opened that url, the problem is solved @ReNiSh